# Date(System.currentTimeInMillis) not working

Tags: java, date, java-calendar

I wanted today's date using the date object so I passed `System.currentTimeInMillis` in `Date()` constructor but it returns the year as 121

Then I used `Calendar` class and it solved my problem, but why wasn't `Date()` class working in the first place?

Comment: `2021-1900=121`

Comment: Why don't you read the Javadocs in the first place?  *the year represented by this date, minus 1900.*

Comment: `new Date()` gives you the current time, using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: Why don't you switch over to the already pretty old "new" java.time API? java.util.Date and the related classes like Calendar have been superseded for years now.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` or an appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Even if you insist on using `Date`, stay far away from its `getYear` method. This and most other methods have been deprecated for 24 years because they work unreliably across time zones.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use only *java.time* classes. Never use the legacy `Date`/`Calendar` classes.

```
java.time.LocalDate.now()
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These classes were written by people who did not understand date-time handling, and who made very poor design choices.

Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on these classes years ago with the unanimous adoption of JSR 310. I suggest you give up on them as well. Use only the *java.time* classes for your date-time work.

### 121 + 1900 = 2021

➥ To answer your specific question: Among the many problems of these legacy classes is that the year is represented as being off by 1900. To quote the Javadoc:

> A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.

So adding 1900 to your year of 121 results in 2021. Mystery solved. But never mind, just move on to using *java.time* instead.

## *java.time*

If you want only the date, without the time-of-day and without a time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
```

Better to specify a desired/expected time zone through which to perceive the current date, rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone, "tomorrow" in Tokyo Japan while still "yesterday" in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want the current moment as seen in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).